# How to search a specific expression in multiple files with Awk

Tags: text, awk

I have like 500 text documents. In every of them the expression "Numero de expediente" appears at least once. I want to locate every file where there is at least twice. Every file has its own name, I'm not sure if that's a problem (I don't know if `*.txt` works as in cmd with Windows). So yeah, I would like to know which document contain that expression at least twice and I don't know which command is more useful for that, if `grep` or `cat`.

Thanks.

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output plus what you've tried so far. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: *(I can't believe this question with no input, no output, and no code has multiple answers when other questions get downvoted and closed for just being missing one of the 3!)*

Comment: I understand a minimal, complete, verifiable and reproducible example is needed for most question people drop here, but given the question it's pretty clear what I want to do, and the multiple answers giving me possible solutions is, I think, the proof for it. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: You're welcome but the fact that at least one of the answers doesn't produce the output you expect and the fact that that there's a far more efficient answer possible (if I understand your requirements) than the one you've accepted together mean that not everyone understands your requirements and many people are just skipping your question so a [mcve] would have been very beneficial to you and to the people trying to help you.

Comment: There are a lot of examples where a question has a reproducible problem and nevertheless the possible solutions people give for it doesn't produce the expected output, because the most satisfactory solution it's not entirely due to a satisfactory question. If you have though in a "more efficient answer" it's because you completely understood the problem and thought about a possible solution.

Comment: Nonetheless, I already wrote that one of the solution worked as I expected: it gives me a list of the name of the documents where there is a repeated expression I want to get rid of. That's what I wanted and that's what I got with the help of the community. There are a lot of causes about why a question remains unsolved/skipped and one of them it is surely because a bad question, but that's not my case. I won't argue anymore: you just think I presented a bad question and I don't think so. I just solved the problem I had and that's all that matters to me. Thank you for your time, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As per @kent and @tripleee sir's comments I am taking care of multiple instances in a single line sum of string's occurences + if someone `awk` is NOT supporting `nextfile` I am creating a flag kind of `no_processing` which will simply skip lines if it is TRUE(after seeing 2 instances of string in any file).

```
awk 'FNR==1{count=0;no_processing=""} no_processing{next} {count+=gsub("Numero de expediente","")} count==2{print FILENAME;no_processing=1}' *.txt
```

OR(non-one liner form of solution)

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  count=0
  no_processing=""
}
no_processing{
  next
}
{
  count+=gsub("Numero de expediente","")
}
count==2{
  print FILENAME
  no_processing=1
}
' *.txt
```

---

---

Could you please try following, should work with GNU `awk`.

```
awk 'FNR==1{count=0} /Numero de expediente/{count++} count==2{print FILENAME " has at least 2 instances of searched string in it.";nextfile}' *.txt
```

Above will print eg--> `test.txt has at least 2 instances of string in it.` In case you want to simply print file names then try following.

```
awk 'FNR==1{count=0} /Numero de expediente/{count++} count==2{print FILENAME;nextfile}' *.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding expplanation for above code now.

```
awk '                          ##Starting awk program here.
FNR==1{                        ##Checking condition FNR==1 which will check if this is a 1st line for any new Input_file(since we are reading multiple Input_files from awk in this code).
  count=0                      ##Setting value of variable count as ZERO here.
}                              ##Closing BLOCK for FNR condition here.
/Numero de expediente/{        ##Checking condition here if a line contains string Numero de expediente in it then do following.
  count++                      ##Incrementing variable named count value with 1 here.
}                              ##Closing BLOCK for string checking condition here.
count==2{                      ##Checking condition if variable count value is 2 then do following.
  print FILENAME               ##Printing Input_file name here, where FILENAME is out of the box awk variable contains current Input_file name in it.
  nextfile                     ##nextfile will skip current Input_file, since we got 2 instances so need NOT to read this Input_file as per OP requirement and SAVE some time here.
}                              ##Closing BLOCK for count condition here.
' *.txt                        ##Mentioning *.txt which will pass all .txt extension files to it.
```

Comment: if the pattern is `foo`, think about a file with a  single line: `foo bar foo`, this should be in the output.

Comment: Maybe note that `nextfile` might not be supported in crufty old Awk implementations like you are somewhat more likely to find on Windows if you download some third-party Sourceforge port from 1993.

Comment: I would do `gsub` instead of `/pat/`, and check the sum of `gsub()` results.

Comment: @Kent, BINGO, I too thought the same and added the solution now sir, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @tripleee, sure sir, I have come up with a flag kind of approach if someone's `awk` is not having `nextfile` though it will NOT jump to next file but will skip all lines simply once it finds 2 instances of string in a file.

Comment: @Kent, thank you for letting know, have removed `grep` solution now from my post.

Comment: Ookay so `awk 'FNR==1{count=0;no_processing=""} no_processing{next} {count+=gsub("Numero de expediente","")} count==2{print FILENAME;no_processing=1}' *.txt` worked flawlessly for my purposes! Thank you very much for your time guys, this community rocks :).

Answer (score 2):

I would add another way with `grep` and `awk`. `grep` is responsible for matching. `awk` filters out the files with matched counter>=2:

```
grep -o -m2 'YOUR_PATTERN' *.txt
 |awk -F: '{a[$1]++}END{for(x in a)if(a[x]>1)print x}'
```

Note:

- `-o` works with multiple occurrences in same line case
- `-m2` will improve the performance: after hits two matches, stop processing the file.
- awk line just builds up a hashtable, and output the filenames with match count > 1

Comment: sir IMHO, how about `grep -o -m2 -l 'umero de expediente' *.txt` taken inspiration from your `grep`. This should directly print the file name and we may need not to process its file names to `awk`.(if you would not mind I have added this edited command to my solution too, kindly do let me know if you want to edit it in your post itself, I will remove it from my post then :) )

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 adding `-l` will make the command fail. Because we want the `duplicated` filenames. `-l` will do something like `uniq`, which in this case **not**  what we wanted.

Comment: apologies if I didn't get something, I just checked with 3 files(out of them 2 files were having this string more than 2 times) and it printed both of the file names on console, kindly do let me know what I missed here please.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 the problem is: with `-l`: File with single match will be displayed in output too. `m2` is `max-count` instead of `at-least-count`

Comment: This solution gives me a list of every document in the folder so I'm not sure what am I doing wrong. Nevertheless, one of the solution @RavinderSingh13 wrote works well for my purposes! Thank you very much for your time guys!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with Perl as well

```
perl -lne ' $x++ for(/Numero de expediente/g); if($x>=2) { print $ARGV;close(ARGV);$x=0 } ' *.txt
```

The $x will be 0 and for every pattern match (Numero de expediente) it will be incremented, even if the pattern is appearing twice in the same line. When you have atleast 2 matches, the file handle is closed using close(ARGV) and the nextfile is read.